# Invertibility of the first Hilbert-Bernays condition in $\omega$-consistent theories

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, provability

I am reading the [Wikipedia article about the Hilbert–Bernays provability conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Bernays_provability_conditions) and I don't understand the following place there:

> The condition that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent is generalized by the condition that if for every formula $\varphi$, if $T$ proves  $\operatorname{Prov}(\sharp\varphi)$, then $T$ proves $\varphi$. Note that this indeed holds for an $\omega$-consistent $T$ because $\operatorname{Prov}(\sharp\varphi)$ means that there is a number coding for the proof of $\varphi$, and if $T$ is $\omega$-consistent then going through all natural numbers one can actually find such a particular number $a$, and then one can use $a$ to construct an actual proof of $\varphi$ in $T$.

I am trying to write the formal proof of this but one step in it remains vague to me, it is evident for me that I don't understand something important. Can anybody help me with this?

The chain of arguments that I can restore is the following. We consider a formal theory $T$ that interprets PA with the universe $U$ in the variable $x$, and we endow it with the numeration $\sharp$ of variables, terms, formulas, proofs, etc.

First, we formulate the $\omega$-consistency of $T$ as follows (I am trying to follow the definition of [G.Takeuti's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486490734) , is that correct?):

> for each formula $\varphi$ in $T$ in variable $x$ if the formula
> $$
> \exists x\quad (U\ \&\ \varphi)
> $$
> is derivable in $T$, then there exists a closed term $\tau$ in PA for which the formula
> $$
> \neg\varphi\Big|_{x=\tau'}
> $$
> is not derivable in $T$

($\tau'$ means the interpretation in the theory $T$ of the term $\tau$ in PA).

Second, let $\operatorname{Prf}$ be the predicate symbol that defines $\operatorname{Prov}$:
$$
\operatorname{Prov}(\sharp\varphi)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \exists x\quad U(x)\ \&\ \operatorname{Prf}(x,\sharp\varphi)
$$

Now the proof of this proposition in Wikipedia, as far as I understand it, must be the following. We assume that $\operatorname{Prov}(\sharp\varphi)$ is derivable in $T$. This leads to the following chain:
$$
\text{$\exists x\ U(x)\ \&\ \operatorname{Prf}(x,\sharp\varphi)$ is derivable in $T$}
$$
$$
\phantom{\text{($T$ is $\omega$-consistent)}} \qquad \Downarrow \qquad \text{($T$ is $\omega$-consistent)}
$$
$$
\text{there exists a closed term $\tau$ in PA such that $\neg\operatorname{Prf}(\tau',\sharp\varphi)$ is not derivable in $T$}
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
\text{there exists a closed term $\tau$ in PA such that $\operatorname{Prf}(\tau',\sharp\varphi)$ is derivable in $T$}
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
\text{$\varphi$ is derivable in $T$}
$$

I don't understand the second implication in this chain. Why is it true? Or if there is a mistake in these considerations, then what is the formal proof of this statement?

Comment: What is $U(x)$?

Comment: @MarkSaving I mean that when $T$ interprets PA there must be a predicate in $T$ that serves as the universe of this interpretation. $U$ is this predicate here. As far as I understand, usually people don't mention this detail.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Prf}{Prf}$

We have some term $\tau$ such that $T \nvdash \neg \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$.

Now in particular, all closed terms in Peano arithmetic evaluate to actual natural numbers. So WLOG, let $\tau$ be an actual natural number (or equivalently its encoding in PA) such that $T \nvdash \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$.

Here is where we need to discuss the specific form that $\Prf$ takes. $\Prf$ is the Peano arithmetic representation of a primitive recursive predicate $P$. $P(x, y)$ is the metatheoretic predicate “$x$ is the Gödel number of a proof in $T$ of a sentence with Gödel number $y$“ in the metatheory - equivalently, we can write $P = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \mid x$ is the Gödel number of a proof in $T$ of a sentence with Gödel number $y\}$. And $\Prf$, by construction, is a strong representation of $P$, meaning that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{N} (P(x, y) \to PA \vdash \Prf(x, y))$ and $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{N} (\neg P(x, y) \to PA \vdash \neg \Prf(x, y))$.

Now either $P(\tau, \# \phi)$ or $\neg P(\tau, \# \phi)$. In the former case, we have come up with an explicit $\tau$ which encodes a proof in $T$ of $\phi$. Therefore, $T \vdash \phi$ - exactly what we wanted to show. I claim the latter case is impossible. For if $\neg P(\tau, \# \phi)$, then $PA \vdash \neg \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$ by the fact that $\Prf$ is a strong representation of $P$. Since $T$ interprets $PA$, we know that $T \vdash \neg \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$. But we assumed at the beginning that $T \nvdash \neg \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$. So we have arrived at a contradiction.

Informally, we can look at $\tau$ and determine whether it actually is a proof of $\phi$. If it is not a proof of $\phi$, then we can prove within $T$ that $\tau$ is not a proof of $\phi$. This contradicts our assumption.

Comment: Mark, when you write "if $\neg P(\tau,\sharp\phi)$" and "so $\neg P(\tau,\sharp\phi)$ is impossible", do you mean "if $PA\vdash \neg P(\tau,\sharp\phi)$" and "so $PA\not\vdash \neg P(\tau,\sharp\phi)$" respectively?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov $\DeclareMathOperator{Prf}{Prf}$ What I mean is that if $\neg P(\tau, \# \phi)$, then $T \vdash \neg \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$, but this contradicts our assumption that $T \nvdash \neg \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$.

Comment: Mark, I must say, I don't understand something. How can just a formula in PA (namely, $\neg P(\tau,\sharp\phi)$) imply derivability of a formula in $T$ (namely, $\neg \operatorname{Prf}(\tau,\sharp\phi)$)? Perhaps, you mean that the derivability of  $\neg P(\tau,\sharp\phi)$ in PA implies the derivability of $\neg \operatorname{Prf}(\tau,\sharp\phi)$ in $T$?

Comment: Mark, also I think in your answer "and therefore $T\vdash \operatorname{Prf}(\tau,\#\phi)$" must be replaced by "and therefore $T\vdash \neg\operatorname{Prf}(\tau,\#\phi)$", is that true?

Comment: I would think that in this proof people assume the completeness of $T$: since $\neg\operatorname{Prf}(\tau,\#\phi)$ cannot be derived, then $\operatorname{Prf}(\tau,\#\phi)$ must be derived. But, as far I understand, this contradicts the $\omega$-consistency of $T$.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov You were correct about the typo. I have clarified the proof somewhat. $P$ is not a formula in $PA$ but rather is a matatheoretic predicate. Essentially, we must assume that the nature of proofs in $T$ is such that we can check through some algorithmic process whether $\tau$ actually is (the Gödel number of) a proof of $\phi$. If this check tells us $\tau$ isn't a proof of $\phi$, then we've come up with a proof that $\tau$ isn't a proof of $\phi$ which can be encoded into $PA$. So $PA \vdash \neg \Prf(\tau, \# \phi)$. This is formally captured by the notion of representability.

Comment: @Sergei But there is no need to assume the completeness of $T$. You are correct that $T$ cannot be both complete, recursive, and consistent (and $\omega$-consistent clearly implies consistent).

Comment: Mark, does this mean that we can reformulate the condition of $\omega$-consistency as follows: "for each formula $\varphi$ in $T$ in variable $x$ if the formula $\exists x\ (U\ \&\ \varphi)$ is derivable in $T$, then there exists a closed term $\tau$ in PA for which the formula $\varphi\Big|_{x=\tau'}$ is derivable in $T$" ?

Comment: Mark, and these writings -- "$P(x, y) \to PA \vdash \operatorname{Prf}(x, y)$" and "$\neg P(x, y) \to PA \vdash \neg \operatorname{Prf}(x, y)$" -- they must be formulas in which theory?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov No, we cannot reformulate $\omega$-consistency in this way, since your reformulation implies completeness. For instance, we could have $\phi(x) \equiv x = 0 \land P \lor x = 1 \land \neg P$ for any sentence $P$. 
$P(x, y) \to PA \vdash Prf(x, y)$ is a formula in the metatheory.

Comment: Mark, I guess by metatheory people mean the one, where the initial theory $T$ is encoded, i.e. in this case this must be PA with the extended signature (the new terms like $\#\varphi$, the new predicate $P$, etc.), right?